# Could this non-Hausdorff world with two skies be logically coherent?

Tags: alien-geometry

Dicaelus is a strange world. It is flat, with a deep sea covering the world. Above this sea are endless archipelagos of floating islands

The strange part is that the vertical axis is not a regular axis, but is instead a branching line. This is where there are two lines that are identified on only one side of the origin. The origin in this world is between the islands and the sea, with one sea and two distinct skies and sets of islands. Objects can cross the origin from either sky to the sea, or from the sea into either sky

Given the strange nature of this place, could such a world logically exist?

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "vertical axis is a branching line".  Until that's explained in a coherent manner this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @sphennings it's a forked world.. projecting from below a certain surface you got 2 points per euclidean point above the surface ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold

Comment: @sphennings Is my explanation OK?

Comment: Try describing your world and how it works instead of copying terms from Wikipedia.

Comment: @sphennings What more about my world must I describe? I can't see any more that is relevant to the question

Comment: What do you even mean by logically coherent? All you need to say is "These are the rules of my world." and as long as you follow those rules then that will be the case. Worlbuilders have created flatlands, long earths, castles in the sky, or disks atop elephants atop turtles. Literally any fantastic geometry can work if you want it to. If you're wanting to know if it's coherent then you're going to describe how your world works and ask us if we see any contradictions.

Comment: @sphennings Rules aren't inherently coherent by virtue of being rules. For example, if you have a ruleset that says that your world is infinite and is entirely surrounded by a boundary, you'll find that to be quite inconsistent

Comment: But you're not asking "Is my world internally consistent" You're asking if it could exist. And the answer to that question is "Sure, if you want it to". There's nothing inherently problematic with having an ocean with two skies, if you choose to let that be your world. So that brings us to what are you actually asking for. Does your most recent wikipedia trolling buzzword fit the limited description you've provided?

Comment: @sphennings Internal consistency is a prerequisite for being able to coherently exist

Comment: Some mathematician who knows their alternative geometries is really needed to answer this categorically,but I think it will boil down to what your criterion is for which sky is interacted with. As far as I can guess, it's no different to having another, orthogonal dimension to the usual three. How it's physically coherent is probably much harder; questions about orbits and gravity arise immediately.

Comment: Internal consistency with what? I for instance can say "My world has two skies, a deep sea and floating islands" there can't be anything contradictory since I haven't used these facts for anything. If you want to ask "Could a non-hausdorff axis be used as an explanation for a world with two skies" try asking that instead. Logical consistency and coherency only exists when you begin applying the facts. If I state as an axiom "false things are true" it's logically consistent because I haven't applied a logic yet.

Comment: *"For example, if you have a ruleset that says that your world is infinite and is entirely surrounded by a boundary, you'll find that to be quite inconsistent":* no it is not. The interval (0, 1) contains infinitely many points, and yet it has both an upper and a lower boundary.

Comment: I'd need a diagram of such a planet to even understand the question.

Comment: What is a "Hausdorff"?

Comment: Okay, I have gone and gotten a PhD on the subject and it turns out Hausdorfness is not required to describe your world mathematically and is only a distraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Yes.

This makes perfect sense.

This logically exists in the real world. All you have to do is, for example, put your kid in front in front of you and see in her face every day of her life from the spark of her first origin to the moment of her last breath. Not as a linear movie with distinct images, but as polytemporal snapshot.

The world you're describing is similar only with solid polyphysicality rather than iconic polytemporality.

Think about it, perhaps, like this:

Plant a tree with a Y shaped trunk. Train the upper part of the wye to converge. Once the two upper trunks are *dually parallel*, bind them until the two Y trunk *looks like* an I trunk.

The unified trunk down by the ground is the Sea. The two skies are the bound Y trunks up above.

If you could place a very tiny exploratory vehicle inside one of the upper trunks, you'd be able to drive it up and down either side of the wye, but you couldn't cross between one and the other.

From the outside, all the leaves --- the islands of the two skies --- look like a single tangle of leaves.

The reason why this description fails, of course, is because of the limitations of our local geometry. What you would end up with is someone who lives on an island in Bluesky, can't see or interact with someone who lives on an island in Greensky, where logically both are in the same place.

Bluesky girl has to descend towards the Sea where she can see both Bluesky and Greensky coexisting in the same place. Thence she must ascend through Greensky to visit her friend who literally lives in the same exact place, only under a different sky.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** I misunderstood the question and have given the formulae for a world with two seas and two skies -- rather than one sea and two skies. The Old version is at the end of this post.

---

**It Works Fine**

Imagine some red ants living on a one dimensional line. Imagine some yellow ants living on a different one dimensional line. One day the lines cross over to make a cross. The cross provides a way for ants to pass from one line to another.
Then someone takes two of the four arms of the cross and smooshes them together into a Y shape. What you have is a three dimensional version of the above.

To describe your forked universe mathematically, consider the Y shape in the $xy$ plane and expand the arms $A,B,C$ to be infinitely long. The entire universe space is the subset $Y \times \mathbb R ^2$. The skies are $A\times \mathbb R ^2$ and $B\times \mathbb R ^2$. The sea is $C\times \mathbb R ^2$. Each looks like a half-infinite line times  $\mathbb R ^2$. In other words a three dimensional space with a ceiling. All three ceilings are the same -- namely the midpoint times $\mathbb R^2$ which is a plane. The plane between the sea and the skies.

Mathematically speaking there is nothing special about the seas compared to the skies. This is just three 3d spaces meeting along a 2d boundary.

There is no need to mention Hausdorfness or non-Hausdorfness.

---

**It Works Fine**

Imagine some red ants living on a one dimensional line. Imagine some yellow ants living on a different one dimensional line. One day the lines cross over to make a cross. The cross provides a way for ants to pass from one line to another. What you have is a three dimensional version of the above.

We can write this down in coordinates. There is a four-dimensional space $\mathbb R^4$ that contains two three dimensional *universes* $$A = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,0): x_1,x_2,x_3 \in\mathbb R\}$$ $$B = \{(0,x_2,x_3,x_4): x_2,x_3,x_4 \in\mathbb R\}.$$ The intersection is the two dimensional sheet $$A \cap B  = \{(0,x_2,x_3,0): x_1,x_2,x_3 \in\mathbb R\}$$ which is between your sea and sky.

The difficult part is how the physics works at the intersection. Will the forces that keep atoms together in a 3-dimensional space still work at the intersection the space is 4-dimensional? I presume you don't want to worry about that. So don't worry about that.

And how the heck does one decide to move into one universe and not the other? Perhaps it depends on your angle of approach. This would also determine which universe one sees when they look up.

**BUT!**

This has nothing to do with Hausdorffness!

Non Hausdorfness is when a space contains more than one points that occupy the same location but that do not touch each other. I'd avoid this terminology unless you have a background in university level maths.

Non Hausdorffness is an abstract mathematical notion and no one seriously tries to use it to describe physical spaces.

What you have here MIGHT be described using **identification** which is pretty much the opposite. You take two points and treat them as one point. It is the maths language for splicing those two lines together to make a cross.

Perhaps it is confusing the Wikipedia example of a non-Hausdorff space also uses identification.

[image]

That thing at the bottom. That's the identification.

If we wanted to describe the 3d example using identification we would write

$$A = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,1): x_1,x_2,x_3 \in\mathbb R\}$$ $$B = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,2): x_1,x_2,x_3 \in\mathbb R\}.$$

Two three dimensional spaces embedded in a 4d space. The equivalence relation stitches them together along the planes where $x_3=0$.

$$ (x_1,x_2,0,1) \simeq (x_1,x_2,0,2) \text{ for all } x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R$$

Comment: I took the OP's description to be using the equivalence relation $(x_1,x_2,x_3,1) \cong (x_1,x_2,x_3,2)$ for all $x_3<0$, not the situation you describe which solely identifies the xy plane and is neither non-hausdorff nor a manifold

Comment: @elduderino You are right I misinterpreted the question. SOMEONE wants to have islands in the sky and not the sea, and this makes speed reading the question a bad idea.

Comment: @elduderino Both my examples are Hausdorff because the first one is a subset of Euclidean space and the second one is equivalent.

Comment: @elduderino Really the Hausdorfness is irrelevant here. If you were to use $x_3 \le 0$ instead you would get a Hausdorff quotient, and it would describe the forked universe just as well as using $x_3 < 0$.

Comment: I see your point and I semi-agree with it-- after all, the difference between the two only matters at a surface of zero volume so you can probably get most physical arguments to agree given a proper limiting procedure at the $x_3=0$ plane. Still, there are important distinctions between the two that make the gluing for $x_3<0$ more natural to use. Namely, if you do so you get a manifold, so that at every point everything looks like 3D euclidean space-- a natural setting for calculus. If you glue $x_3 \ leq 0$ instead, the physical interpretation is more clouded, or at least more alien.