# Is this material topologically sound?

Tags: alien-geometry

The material is a normal substance, made of atoms and compounds just as in reality. However, it exists in a non-Hausdorff realm, and has a unique property relating to that: Unlike most objects, which only interact with things that come into contact, this material can be struck by any collocated objects or forces, even if they are in a completely different branch of the world. In other words, they treat the world as if it were a Hausdorff manifold, though it is not

Could such a material work as described, or does it result in some sort of contradiction or unforseen extra effects that make it impossible or unworkable?

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about the way it works... is there faster than light transmission of information/energy because of this? How does being acted on by.. say Coriolis force or the various forces inherent in being (affected) on different parts of a planet simultaneously in all different directions work?

Comment: It's basically magic, so it works the way you say it works.

Comment: Wait, is this a Hausdorff realm or not? From what I understand, you're asking if a material that can be affected from a distance could form paradoxes according to... Topology instead of physics?

Comment: Just say what the rules of the world are. Avoid the Hasudorff terminology unless you have a background in university level math.

Comment: @AngryMuppet I think it has something to do with two particles occupying the same space. That's what "colocated" means. And usually the particle does notinteract with the colocated one, unless it is made of this special matter.  There is no mention of FTL transmission or planets. We don't even know if this world has planets.

Comment: @AngryMuppet It is also possible the asker is simply in love with the concept of nonHausdorfness and has not decided exactly what it means in their world. They have [another question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/228326/could-this-non-hausdorff-world-with-two-skies-be-logically-coherent/228345#228345) where the non Hausdorffness means something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

**Extra Dimensions**

It sounds like you have a special type of matter that can travel through normal (colocated) matter. However the special matter cannot travel through a wall made of other special matter, even if it is colocated.

This happens because the special matter can move in an extra dimension to everything else. So it can go around the normal matter by phasing into the extra dimension.

But the way the special matter interacts with itself is also extra-dimensional. Instead of creating an electric field like an electron, it creates a special field that extends into the extra dimension. So the special matter cannot go through the special wall.

Another option is you have two "layers" say two 3D universes 1 billion miles apart in the extra dimension. So protons in layer 1 do not influence protons in layer 2. But the special particles are 1 billion miles deep. So they influence everything in both universes.

Answer (score 1):

**Atoms are mostly empty space**

It sounds like you want particles occupying the same space as each other, and sometimes they touch or interact with each other and sometimes they don't.

That's what I presume you mean by "colocated". The word usually means using the same building for two things. Like having a maternity hospital be in the same building as a paediatric hospital. If you mean something else then explain it.

Here's the thing -- this overlapping particle mumbo-jumbo already happens all the time. Atoms are mostly empty space. Other particles can move through this space provided they do not interact with the electric fields from the electrons. Neutrinos shoot through miles and miles of normal matter as though it is not there.

Likewise one particle is free to sit in the same space as an atom provided there is something keeping it there. This is how dark matter is theorized to work.

The take home is you do not need to worry about separation axioms in physical space. Just worry creating new types of particles that do what you want.